# Table catalogsearch_fulltext DOES NOT contain an indexed product (Magento CE 1.9.1.0)

Tags: product, catalogsearch, indexing, reindex

Im having `a large DB with over 800k products` and `successfully complete reindexing via SSH` but when try to look for the new products `i have added, they cant be found.`